# Why LEFT JOIN give me always the primery id value in MySQL for Python?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mariadb

I have the next GUI made in Python which lets me to load all the data saved in a MySQL table for tenants, and just one data from a related table called 'contracts' (marked with a red circle).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzcqm.png)

The Python code I use for loading this form is the next one:

```
def fill_entries():
        i = lb.curselection()[0]
        valor = lb.get(i)
        nombs, apells = _arrendatarios[valor]
        cursor.execute("SELECT *, c_cod FROM arrendatarios LEFT JOIN contratos ON arrendatarios.a_cc = contratos.a_cc WHERE a_nombres = %s AND a_apellidos = %s", (nombs, apells))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        connect.commit()
        for item in result:
                d1 = item[1] #ID
                d2 = item[2] #Mr/Mrs
                d3 = item[3] #City
                d4 = item[4] #Names
                d5 = item[5] #Last names
                #------------And so on
                d53 = item[53] # Num Contract

                cedula.set(d1)
                titulo.set(d2)
                residencia.set(d3)
                nombres.set(d4)
                apellidos.set(d5)
                direccion.set(d6)
                #------------And so on
                numcontract.set(d53)# Num Contract
```

But the thing is that what I want from the contracts table is the `c_cod` data, not de `c_id`, because part of this table description is this:

```
MariaDB> desc contratos;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| c_id          | int(11)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| c_cod         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| a_cc          | varchar(50)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| inquilino     | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And if, for example, I run the query in MySQL I got this:

```
MariaDB> SELECT arrendatarios.a_cc, c_cod FROM arrendatarios LEFT JOIN  contratos ON arrendatarios.a_cc = contratos.a_cc;
+------------+-------+
| a_cc       | c_cod |
+------------+-------+
| 900157048  |  NULL |
| 71337237   |  NULL |
| 43057196   | 22789 |
| 542550033  |  NULL |
| 3502278    |  NULL |
| 3472265    |  NULL |
| 32460023   |  NULL |
| And so on...       |
+------------+-------+
34 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

But Python is not drawing me the `c_cod` from contracts table but the `c_id` as if I were running:

```
MariaDB> SELECT arrendatarios.a_cc, c_id FROM arrendatarios LEFT JOIN contratos ON arrendatarios.a_cc = contratos.a_cc;
+------------+------+
| a_cc       | c_id |
+------------+------+
| 900157048  | NULL |
| 71337237   | NULL |
| 43057196   |    8 |
| 542550033  | NULL |
| 3502278    | NULL |
| 3472265    | NULL |
| 32460023   | NULL |
| And so on...      |
+------------+------+
34 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

No matter what column I write, it always draws me the same result, the `c_id`. I'm a newbie with MySQL, I just new the basic. So, am I using wrong LEFT JOIN? Because what I want is just to show tenant info and this contract number n matter if it has it or not.

Here's the description of the tenants table too.

```
MariaDB> desc arrendatarios;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| a_id            | int(11)      | NO   | UNI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| a_cc            | varchar(50)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| a_titulo        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_reside        | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_nombres       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_apellidos     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_direccion     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_telefono      | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_envio         | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_email         | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_celular       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_dia           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_mes           | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_cumple        | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_profesion     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_empresa       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_oficina       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_tel           | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_fax           | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_banco         | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_tcuenta       | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_numcuenta     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_tpersona      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_retefuente    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_reteiva       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_contribuyente | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_gfactura      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_gcheque       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| a_nota          | varchar(200) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co1_cc          | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co1_nombres     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co1_dir         | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co1_tel1        | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co1_cargo       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co1_empresa     | varchar(59)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co1_oficina     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co1_tel2        | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co2_cc          | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co2_nombres     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co2_dir         | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co2_tel1        | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co2_cargo       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co2_empresa     | varchar(59)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co2_oficina     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co2_tel2        | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co3_cc          | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co3_nombres     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co3_dir         | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co3_tel1        | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co3_cargo       | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co3_empresa     | varchar(59)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co3_oficina     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| co3_tel2        | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
53 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Comment: Can you run desc arrendatios? What happens if you run the query on MySQL? Have you checked the record you point, it looks you are expecting a field to contain some info that it is not contained there.

Comment: BTW, adding personal information of a customer/user is not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Picarus! I corrected the pic, and yes, I've checked all the data because I have just 34 records in tenants table and 8 in contracts. That means that just those tenants who have contract show their id, and the rest draw a 'None' in the entry of the GUI. I wrote at he end of the post the tenants desc, it's a little big!

Comment: `SELECT *, c_coid` will give you every column in your query (all columns of table 1, then all columns of table 2, then `c_coid`). So column 53 is the first column of table 2. While you can use `SELECT arrendatarios.*, c_coid` to fix it, this is a very good example of why you should not use `*`, especially if you use the column position (53) in python - as your code will break as soon as you add another column to table 1. So although it is annoying, list every column you want to get in your query (just like in your working example with 2 columns) and (or at least) use field names in python.

Comment: Thanks @Solarflare! That solved it!

Comment: Do not splay an array (co1/2/3) across columns; make another table.

Answer (score 0):

As commented this solved the problem:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT arrendatarios.*, c_cod FROM arrendatarios LEFT JOIN contratos ON arrendatarios.a_cc = contratos.a_cc WHERE a_nombres = %s AND a_apellidos = %s", (nombs, apells))
```